# Unfocus window which is on top

Tags: compiz, focus, ccsm

I have certain apps which I want to be on top (I set it via window's menu: `Alt-Space` + `"Always on top"`). But when I switch between apps by pressing `Alt-Tab` once, these windows steal focus. This happens when I close active window also. Is there a way to make window un-focusable to prevent this? I tried to solve this via ccsm: `General options`/`Focus & Raise behavior`/`Focus Prevention Windows` but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go, is to tell window switcher to ignore it.

1. Install `ccsm`& run it
2. Desktop category → Ubuntu Unity plugin → Switcher tab

   Disable all its shortcuts.
3. Enable alternative switcher

   Window management category → Application switcher

   - Check enable application switcher
   - General tab → change Switcher windows to exclude your specific windows.

     Example for gnome-terminal:

     ```
     (Toolbar | Utility | Dialog | Normal | Unknown) & !(name=gnome-terminal-server)
     ```

You could even use dual switcher:

- Set <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> & <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for application switcher
- and live set <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> & <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for unity switcher

So current desktop window switcher will skip it but the all window switcher will not. Best of both worlds